# Silverlight Navigation + MVC Routing

Tags: silverlight, model-view-controller, navigation, prism, deep-linking

I am experimenting with Silverlight (4.0) Navigation and deep linking. The problem I'm facing now is that my Silverlight application is hosted inside a MVC view page (.cshtml) as shown below, which is fairly standard.

```
<object id="SilverlightAdvanceAdminObject" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
        <!-- omitted for brevity -->
</object>
```

At this stage, my URI is routed by MVC, so I would have a Admin controller which has a Advanced action which in turn returns the above view.

eg. http://localhost/Admin/Advanced

From here on out, I would like MVC to allow me to perform a Silverlight Navigation to 'deep link' into a view inside my SL app.

eg. http://localhost/Admin/Advanced#/Users

Uri Mapper:

```
<sdk:Frame region:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion">
    <sdk:Frame.ContentLoader>
        <prism:FrameContentLoader RegionName="MainRegion" />
    </sdk:Frame.ContentLoader>
    <sdk:Frame.UriMapper>
        <sdk:UriMapper>
            <sdk:UriMapping Uri="" MappedUri="/UserAdminView" />
            <sdk:UriMapping Uri="/{viewName}" MappedUri="/{viewName}" />
        </sdk:UriMapper>
    </sdk:Frame.UriMapper>
</sdk:Frame>
```

The above example is something I would like to achieve, where the Users component of the URI is a view inside my SL application which is managed by a UriMapper. At the moment, this doesn't seem to work.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would usually wait for an answer, but I found this problem to be a bit of a lemon. For the Silverlight applicaiton to receive the URI routes, you need to a an `iframe` with a specific id into the page hosting the SL.

```
<iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe>
```

I have no idea why this is not mentioned anywhere that can be easily seen, but apparently missed because if you use the Silveright Navigation project template, this would have been added for you automatically.

Good one MS! =.=